# GEE CoLab How to clip a mosaic to a geometry from a shapefile?

Tags: google-earth-engine, polygon, geometry, mosaic, google-colab

Is there a way I can somehow grab the geometry from a polygon in a shapefile and use that to cut out my Landsat mosaic? I want my mosaic only to appear within the black-outlined polygon below.

[image]

```
Map = geemap.Map()


vis_params = {
    'color': '000000', 
    'pointSize': 3,
    'pointShape': 'circle',
    'width': 2,
    'lineType': 'solid',
    'fillColor': '00000000',
}

visParams = {
       'bands': ['SR_B3_2', 'SR_B2_2', 'SR_B1_2'], 
       'min': 0,                    
       'max': 0.4,
       'gamma': 1.4,                
     }

Map.addLayer(l5_sr_mosaic, visParams, 'Landsat 5 Quality Mosaic')
Map.addLayer(aoiformap, {}, "Elma_01", False)
Map.addLayer(aoiformap.style(**vis_params), {}, "Elma_01")
```

Comment: Yes, [clipping an image is possible](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-clip). Please [edit] your question to include the code you currently have to load the image and geometry; then we can tell you how to adjust it.

Comment: I've edited. Not sure how to access geometry. Data from arcgis pro. VERY beginner sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `l5_sr_mosaic` to `l5_sr_mosaic.clip(aoiformap)`.

```js
Map.addLayer(l5_sr_mosaic.clip(aoiformap), visParams, 'Landsat 5 Quality Mosaic')
```

Documentation: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-clip